# Grouping grouped items and iterating through first group

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

So I have collections of items which I display in a listview. I use groups to separate the collection on screen for the user, however, in my current implementation, all items in the collection are placed by the first or default item, rather than each item being processed separately within the collection. Below is what I have at the minute. I need to group each item within the collection, with them being treated individually.

UPDATE: To be clear on the collection, I have expanded the example:

```cs
// The collection will go in this
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Book>> result = null;

// Starting by grouping the objects
result =
    from c in Books
    group c by c.Series into g
    select g;
// Now that we have the items grouped we need to group them again, for use with the uwp CollectionViewSource, in effect grouping the grouped items
    GroupStacked(result);

public void GroupStacked(IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Book>> collection)
viewSource.IsSourceGrouped = true;
var result =
   from c in collection
      orderby c.FirstOrDefault().Series
      group c by c.FirstOrDefault().Series into g // rather than this, i need to group each item within the collection, with them being treated individually 
      select g;
ViewSource.Source = result;
```

Comment: Can you show your desired results with an example?

Comment: What are those classes and what do you expect as output? `I need to group each item within the collection, with them being treated individually` is confusing. The code itself would only work if each `c` was an `IEnumerable<>` itself, not an item.

Comment: If you have nested collections and want to group and order the leaf items you could use `from nested in collection from item in nested group by item.Series ...` or `collection.SelectMany(c=>c).Group(item=>item.Series)...`

Comment: I expect out an IGrouping<string, Object>. 

SelectMany isn't an option for me as it will flatten the result.

Comment: Did you try something like this ?
`var result =
   from c in collection
   from s in c.Series
      group c by c into g 
      select g;`

Comment: @Wamiq Rehman The issue with that query is the second 'from' statement. It requires an object, not a collection of objects

Comment: Could share the detail of `collection`, does it like this  `List<List<item>> collection`?

Comment: No it looks like this: IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Object>>

Comment: That is incorrect, the second `from` requires `c.Series` be a collection, but perhaps based on your code it is a single item? It would really help if you updated your question with the full type of `collection`.